# Loading an Image in s:div in a jsp page

Tags: ajax

I have an s:div ajax in jsp page:

```
<s:div 
    theme="ajax" 
    delay="10000" 
    loadingText="Please Wait" 
    errorText="Problem in loading" 
    href="%{yearlyrequestedQuantity}">
</s:div>
```

In this i want to load an image instead of the "please wait" text.

Answer (score 0):

To display a "wait until the page loads" image 
 you will need to:

1. Every time your page loads a `init()` function will load.

   ```
   <body onLoad="init()">
   ```
2. Define a div named `loading` right after  section.

   ```
   <div id="loading" style="position:absolute; width:100%; text-align:center;
   top:300px;">
   <img src="loading.gif" border=0></div>
   ```

The loading.gif image should be an animated gif that suggests that the page is still loading.

1. Place this javascript code right after you define the div.

   ```
   <script>
   var ld=(document.all);
    var ns4=document.layers;
   var ns6=document.getElementById&&!document.all;
   var ie4=document.all;
   if (ns4)
      ld=document.loading;
   else if (ns6)
      ld=document.getElementById("loading").style;
   else if (ie4)
      ld=document.all.loading.style;
   function init()
   {
   if(ns4){ld.visibility="hidden";}
   else if (ns6||ie4) ld.display="none";
   }
   </script>
   ```